# Case Insensitive filtering using Google Guava

Tags: guava

Current I am using following piece of code  to create a filter, in a map to match and give a filtered list of resultset.

```
final Map filteredMap = Maps.filterKeys(mymap, Predicates.containsPattern("^Xyz"));
```

However Guava Predicates.containsPattern does case-sensitive matching.

How should I use containsPattern for doing case-Insensitive matching.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use

```
Predicates.contains(Pattern.compile("^Xyz", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE))
```

as predicate instead. See core Java [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) and [`Predicates.contains`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html#contains-java.util.regex.Pattern-).

**EDIT** (after OP's comment): yes, you can write:

```
Predicates.containsPattern("(?i)^Xyz"))
```

(see Pattern's documentation: *Case-insensitive matching can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?i).*) but it's IMO less self-explaining, plus compiled `Pattern` from first example can be cached to some private static final constant when used in a loop, which can improve performance.

Comment: I agree with tht but can we have something like tht for containsPattern scenario.

Comment: Thanks have got my answer. ?i was the part not aware of as strings are immutable generally had equalsIgnorecase in mind will chk out how pattern would use ?i to make it insensitive. Thanks once again